# What is the -l (lowercase L) switch of the ssh-agent command?

Tags: command-line, macos, ssh-agent

I see the following on macOS:

```
$ ps ax | ag ssh-agent
8677   ??  S      0:00.60 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -l
```

Looked up `ssh-agent`'s man page on the terminal, but it has no mention of a `-l` switch. None of the online man pages I found so far (neither [this](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh-agent.1.html) nor [this](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent)) mentions it.

This seems to a macOS-specific feature, but couldn't find it documented anywhere (yet):

```
$ /usr/bin/ssh-agent -l
launch_activate_socket(): No such process

$ which ssh-agent
/nix/store/kgp4br70j8w4k4lgsv8sk22hb51km36s-openssh-9.1p1/bin/ssh-agent                                                                                                                                                                                                       

$ ssh-agent -l
ssh-agent: illegal option -- l
```

Based on [the google results of `/usr/bin/ssh-agent -l` error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=launch_activate_socket()%20no%20such%20process&oq=%22launch_activate&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i512j0i10i15i30j0i8i30l7.5377j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#ip=1), `-l` probably stands for "listener"?

Comment: Duplicate of Stackoverflow thread [_What is `-l` flag in macos ssh-agent?_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72743995/what-is-l-flag-in-macos-ssh-agent).

Answer (score 0):

It's an undocumented flag related to integration with macOS's `launchd`. It's discussed further in this Stackoverflow post: [What is `-l` flag in macos ssh-agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72743995/what-is-l-flag-in-macos-ssh-agent)